# Galaxy S4 Android Custom Camera Issue

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

I'm developing an app with a custom camera. Everything works fine in Motorola Moto G but when I try to save the pictures taken by a Galaxy S4, it takes this aspect:

[image]

CameraSurface.java

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Size previewSize = determinePreviewSize(true, width, height);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);


    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
        if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
            size = sizes.get(i);
    }

    parameters.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);

    parameters.set("display_mode","portrait");
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found myself the solution for the problem described above.

When you set **setPreviewSize** and **setPictureSize** they **MUST** have the same **aspect ratio**. If your method **determinePreviewSize(true, width, height)** returns a size with aspect ratio 16:9 you need to setPictureSize a resolution with the SAME aspect ratio 16:9.

So the solution is to implement a method which selects from **getSupportedPictureSizes()** the best resolution that matches the aspect ratio given by **determinePreviewSize(true, width, height)**